# Django custom managers - how do I return only objects created by the logged-in user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers, django-custom-manager

I want to overwrite the custom objects model manager to only return objects a specific user created. Admin users should still return all objects using the objects model manager.

Now I have found [an approach](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg08691.html) that could work. They propose to create your own middleware looking like this:

```
#### myproject/middleware/threadlocals.py

try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.3 compatibility
    from django.utils._threading_local import local

_thread_locals = local()

def get_current_user():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'user', None)

class ThreadLocals(object):
    """Middleware that gets various objects from the
    request object and saves them in thread local storage."""
    def process_request(self, request):
        _thread_locals.user = getattr(request, 'user', None)

#### end
```

And in the Custom manager you could call the `get_current_user()` method to return only objects a specific user created.

```
class UserContactManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(UserContactManager, self).get_query_set().filter(creator=get_current_user())
```

Is this a good approach to this use-case? Will this work? Or is this like "using a sledgehammer to crack a nut" ? ;-)

Just using:

```
Contact.objects.filter(created_by= user)
```

in each view doesn`t look very neat to me.

#### EDIT Do not use this middleware approach !!!

use the approach stated by Jack M. below

After a while of testing this approach behaved pretty strange and with this approach you mix up a global-state with a current request.

Use the approach presented below. It is really easy and no need to hack around with the middleware.

create a custom manager in your model with a function that expects the current user or any other user as an input.

```
#in your models.py
class HourRecordManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(created_by=user)

class HourRecord(models.Model):
    #Managers
    objects = HourRecordManager()

#in vour view you can call the manager like this and get returned only the objects from the currently logged-in user.

hr_set = HourRecord.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

See also this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087531/django-get-current-user-middleware-strange-error-message-which-goes-away-if-s) about the middelware approach.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to create a new method instead of redefining `get_query_set`.  Something along the lines of:

```
class UserContactManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(UserContactManager, self).get_query_set().filter(creator=user)

class UserContact(models.Model):
    [...]
    objects = UserContactManager()
```

This allows your view to look like this:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

This should help keep your view simple, and because you would be using Django's built in features, it isn't likely to break in the future.

Comment: do we need to modify anything in actual modal? like `safe = SafePictureManager()`

Comment: Yes, when you make a custom manager you have to assign it to the `Model`.  In this case, I assigned it to `objects` so that  `UserContact.ojects.for_user()` is available.

Comment: I have a problem with this, i need request in my `ListView`, but putting `self.request` or `request` i have a problem, how to set the request?

If is needed override the `get_queryset` function in the view, isn't necessary so use managers.

Comment: I have the same issue as SalahAdDin - ' object has no attribute 'request'

Answer (score 6):

It seems necessary to use the middleware to store the user information.

However, I'd rather not modify the *default ModelManager* `objects`, but hook it upto a different manager, that I will use in the code, say in your case `user_objects` instead of objects.

Since you will use this only within views that are `@login_required` you dont need all the complex error handling in the Middleware.

Just my 2¢.

Answer (score -1):

Or even simpler and use foreign key to retrieve queryset.

If you have model like that

```
class HourRecord(models.Model):
    created_by = ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='hour_records')
```

You can query `HourRecords` in a view by user with simply:

```
request.user.hour_records.all()
```