# django - dynamic manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have a model that has an owner field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(...)
```

I extended the django `User` class and added an ownership filed

```
class AppUser(User):
    ownership = models.CharField(...)
```

I want to create a Manager for `MyModel` so it will retrieve only objects that correspond with ownership of the currently logged in user.
For example (using Django REST framework):

```
class MyModelAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # This query will automatically add a filter of owner=request.user.ownership
        objs = MyModel.objects.all()
        # rest of code ...
```

All of the examples of managers user constant values in their queries and i'm looking for something more dynamic. Is this thing even possible?
Thanks

Comment: What is the relation of `MyModel` and `AppUser`? Isn't `owner` supposed to be a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: no... its more of a permissions thing than a foreign key thing. Some users will have a special ownership that will allow them to retrieve all objects of MyModel

Comment: So basically all `MyModel` instances where `owner == request.user.ownership`?

Comment: in the most simplistic example yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with a custom manager because a model manager is instantiated at class loading time. Hence, it is stateless with regard to the http-request-response cycle and could only provide some custom method that you would have to pass the user to anyway. So why don't you just add some convenience method/property on your model (a manager seems unnecessary for this sole purpose)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @clsmethod
    def user_objects(cls, user):
        return cls.objects.filter(owner=user.ownership)
```

Then, in your view:

```
objs = MyModel.user_objects(request.user)
```

For a manager-based solution, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006295/django-custom-managers-how-do-i-return-only-objects-created-by-the-logged-in-u). Another interesting solution is a custom middleware that makes the current user available via some function/module attribute which can be accessed in acustom manager's `get_queryset()` method, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273705/django-access-logged-in-user-in-custom-manager#answer-2276273).

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this approach is that im using Django REST framework so if i have a ListAPIView, i cant really set the correct queryset `queryset = MyModel.objects.owned_by(<what here?>)`

Comment: Actually this is possible and is very useful when testing. You can add manager dynamically by calling `MyModel.add_to_class("mycustommanager", Manager())`

Comment: You can access the request in `get_queryset`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself