# Django custom manager request object/current user

Tags: django, session

I have made a custom manager by creating a class inheriting from `models.Manager`.The manager just changed the default model.objects query to add some filters. Now, I want to add a filter according to the user logged in. I dont want to have to search through code changing what params are added, is there any way I can get the request object/current user without passing it through to the method?

Im hoping this is not a stupid question, but I may just be getting confused...

This is the basic setup of the Manager

```
class pubManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):        
        return pubEnt.objects.filter(state='new')

    def on_site(self):
        return pubEnt.objects.filter(state='old', val=0)
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006295/django-custom-managers-how-do-i-return-only-objects-created-by-the-logged-in-us

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way in django to access the current `request` without passing it. If can't live without it you should probably rethink your design! Having access to the `request` shouldn't be a requirement of a manager's method, since it could also be accessible from somewhere where you do not have a `request` object (think for example of calling the method from the python shell). If you need access to the currently logged-in user, pass the `user` object to the method (from `request.user`), but not the whole `request`!

Answer (score 2):

Global Django requests
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html