# Django custom ModelManagers to implicitly restrict queryets available per user

Tags: django, python-multithreading

My use case is that I want different users to be able to work on their own projects and be restricted from seeing material in other projects, even in the Admin site. There are a number of models that ought to be filtered back to 'project' - for example a concrete Answer extends the Abstract class Answer, which has question as a foreign key and Question which have project as a foreign key.

My plan was to modify the default ModelManager get_queryset() and return a queryset with a filter something like:
 Project.objects.filter(group__in=user.groups.all())

The challenge is for the ModelManager to reliably know which user is calling it, without changing the signature every time a queryset is produced.  I found this solution, which looks extremely smooth:

[Middleware maintaining a dict of requests indexed by the thread handling them](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html)

But its from 2010 and I'm not sure how much Django, Python, thread-handling, the security landscape etc may have changed in the mean time. Is there now a preferred way to do this, with sessions perhaps?

(related problem here: [Django custom manager request object/current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846152/django-custom-manager-request-object-current-user))

Answer (score 0):

Translated to modern day Django, the middleware is:

```
from threading import current_thread

_requests = {}

def get_request():
    return _requests[current_thread()]

class GlobalRequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread()] = request
        return self.get_response(request)
```

I need to import get_request() to access the _requests dict.