# Understanding Django's database API and models - Poll.objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was going through the Django's official Polls Tutorial. I am able to follow the steps and so far able to get the results. But I am not able to understand the structure of Models

While using the API in shell (Polls Tutorial Part 1) one use Polls.objects.all() to list objects Now polls is a class which inherits from models.Model. But what about objects?

Using Poll.objects lists objects to and then we can use the all method on it.

So what exactly is Poll.objects (an instance of something else?) Sorry if this sounds really dumb I am very new to all this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Poll.objects` is a special thing in Django called [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/):

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are
>   provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model
>   in a Django application.

The name `objects` is just a convention/standard that Django follows. You can easily change it:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    whatever = models.Manager()
```

You can also define your custom model manager methods. Often it is really a good way to extract and reuse functionality related to database model interaction. For example:

- [Django custom managers - how do I return only objects created by the logged-in user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006295/django-custom-managers-how-do-i-return-only-objects-created-by-the-logged-in-u)
- [Building a higher-level query API: the right way to use Django's ORM](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/higher-level-query-api-django-orm/)

Comment: So objects is basically an instance models.Manager() :) Am I right to assume that all and other filters are methods in models.Manger()?

Comment: @TarunKumarVangani yeah, `get()`, `filter()` etc are methods of the model manager.

Comment: @TarunKumarVangani FYI, [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py).