# How to change django admin permissions based on a field value?

Tags: python, django

I have a model where a Professor belongs to a certain department

```
Class Professor(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  code=models.CharField(max_length=9)
  dept=models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where the model for the department is just its name with multiple professors pointing to it.

Would there be a way to set view or edit permissions depending on the value of the department name? Say, if I want professors that belong to department A to only be editable by people with permissions to A, and professors belonging to department B to be editable by people with permissions to B and so on, what would be the way to implement it in the admin?

Edit: I have scoured the django docs and I can see no indication of whether it is possible at all to change permissions on the admin based on any model's fields (without manually assigning them an user when creating the object), I'd appreciate being pointed to even a high level overview of how it could be done, or to know why it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

In your admin class, you can try this:

```
class ProfessorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            if obj.dept == "A":
                 return request.user.has_perm('DeptA')
            elif obj.dept == "B":
                 return request.user.has_perm('DeptB')
        return super(ProfessorAdmin, self).has_change_permission(self, request, obj)
```

Here as you can see, we have *access to two important things* :

1. The request context and the **request.user** who wants to change the data. Hence, we can check any property of that user ( **is_superuser / is_staff / has_perm()** ) and customise the logic.
2. The **instance** which is being changed/updated, So, we can customise the logic depending on any field value.

Django docs reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission)

Comment: Thanks, but I have error,so I had to change return with 2 parameters
return super(ProfessorAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, obj)

Answer (score 0):

Recommended read:

https://realpython.com/manage-users-in-django-admin/

So it is possible, just create groups by department, assign editing permissions to each user by department group.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to apply the techniques in that article to solve my problem