# Django: Custom default Manager with user based queries for all views/interfaces (custom, admin, graphene, rest, ...)

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

In Django I'm trying to implement some kind of a "security middleware", which gives access to certain db information only, if the logged in user matches.

Up to now I found two approaches: middleware or custom function in manager (Both explained here [Django custom managers - how do I return only objects created by the logged-in user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006295/1096526)).

Example for cleanest solution: custom function

```py
class UserContactManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(creator=user)

class MyUser(models.Model):
    # Managers
    objects = UserContactManager()

# then use it like this in views
data = MyUser.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

However, this solution only works, if you have control over the code which invokes this custom function (here: `for_user()`).
But if you are using third parties apps like Django-REST, Graphene or AdminViews, they don't have the possibility to configure a specific query-func to use.

#### My goal:

1. Replace the default Manager
2. Add user-based filters to query_set
3. Use the model as normal in all app configurations

**Idea (pseudo code!)**

```py
from django.x import current_user

class UserBasedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author=current_user.name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = UserBasedManager() # The default manager.
```

Now I could use the model `Book` as normal in all extensions.

I know this solution would have some drawbacks, which are okay for me:

- Can be only used when user is available (e.g. no direct script support)
- Handling no or anonymous user is missing (left it away to keep example short)

#### My use case

I have a project, which shall give access to data by different interfaces (admin pages, custom views, rest, graphql).
As I have so many interfaces, I don't want to implement the access-rights in the views. This would cost too much time and is hard to maintain and the risk for security problems in one specific view/interface is too high.

Let's say I'm storing commits of git repositories in a database.
And the user shall get access to all commits, which are part of repos the user has READ access.

The question is: **How can I implement this as a generic, view/interface independent solution?**

Answer (score 1):

Install [django-threadlocals](https://pypi.org/project/django-threadlocals/) package and call *get_current_user* function to get the current user

```
from threadlocals.threadlocals import get_current_user

class UserBasedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = get_current_user()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author=current_user.name)
```

Comment: Looks good but trying to understand the drawbacks of this method (since it's not more widespread)